# change outgoing (send only) email from www-data@ to info@

Tags: apache2, email, postfix

Running Ubuntu Server 16.04
having searched for days and tried many things that did'nt work, here i am.
I have a PHP script that sends email (out bound only) to a list of subscribers and it works fine! however in the header of the email its from www-data@server.com instead of info@server.com. 
I have edited the main.cf

```
======================================
myhostname = server.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#mydestination = server, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$myhostname, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
======================================
```

Thank you for any help on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postfix's `sendmail` binary to send the emails, you can try to set the `sendmail_path` in the `php.ini` configuration file to: `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f info@server.com"`

Comment: i turns out sendmail is what is being used. would this work for that? and if so just add the line to php.ini? thx